# simple python program crashes with SIGBUS (on windows 3221225477)

Tags: python, python-requests, queue, python-multiprocessing

I have a problem with a relatively simple Python code. It simply creates 10 processes, where each process has 100 threads. Each thread then downloads a URL of a page (from different domains) that is received through a queue. The queue is created and filled with about 200.000 URLs in the main process. The downloaded page is then cleaned with a Cleaner and parsed using HTMLParser.

**The program randomly crashes, most frequently less than a minute after running**. The easiest way to reproduce is to restart the program a few times within a minute after running it if the program doesn't crash yet.

The same crash also happens if the number of threads is smaller (e.g. 5) and the number of processes is higher (e.g. 20-50)

The exit code is SIGBUS on Linux or 3221225477 on Windows. Any idea what could be the issue?

```py
import sys, queue, threading, requests, logging, time, traceback
from multiprocessing import Queue, Process
from typing import *
import lxml
from io import StringIO
# import nlputils
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html
import lxml.html.clean
import lxml.html.soupparser

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)
log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
stdoutHandler = logging.StreamHandler(sys.stdout)
stdoutHandler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(message)s', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
stdoutHandler.setLevel(logging.WARNING)
log.addHandler(stdoutHandler)

import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings(urllib3.exceptions.InsecureRequestWarning)

def processArticleQueue(articleQueue: queue.Queue, threadCount: int):

    def taskLoop():
        while True:
            url = articleQueue.get()
            try:
                res = requests.get(url, verify=False, timeout=30)
                res.raise_for_status()
                cleaner = lxml.html.clean.Cleaner()
                parser = lxml.html.HTMLParser(recover=True)

                txt = res.text
                if len(txt) >= 12:
                    try:
                        txt = cleaner.clean_html(txt)
                        clean_dom = lxml.etree.parse(StringIO(txt), parser=parser)
                    except Exception:
                        pass
            except KeyboardInterrupt:
                print("KeyboardInterrupt at taskLoop")
                return
            except Exception as ex:
                pass
            

    log.critical("Creating %d threads" % threadCount)
    # the annotation threads
    threads = []
    for i in range(threadCount):
        t = threading.Thread(target = taskLoop)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)

    # wait until all threads are done
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


def main():
    def pool_is_alive():
        for proc in crawlerPool:
            if not proc.is_alive():
                log.critical('Process/thread %r was found dead unexpectedly', proc)
                return False
        return True

    articleQueue = Queue()

    log.info("Adding tasks...")
    for line in open("../urls/2023-10-02.txt"):
        url = line.split("\t")[0].strip()
        articleQueue.put(url)

    crawlerPool = [
        Process(name=f'{processArticleQueue.__name__}{i}',
                target=processArticleQueue,
                args=(articleQueue, 100))
        for i in range(10)
    ]
    for p in crawlerPool:
        p.start()

    # indefinitely check for new articles added to the collection
    while True:
        assert pool_is_alive(), ('A process/thread has died', crawlerPool)
        log.critical(f"Article queue size: {articleQueue.qsize()}.")
        time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```